# Update Locale with i18n shell

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

Reading the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html) I was able to extract all the strings of my application:

```
bin/cake i18n extract
```

The `Locale/default.pot` file now contains the messages to be translated.
After some time I will need to do it again because I will add some other forms.

I don't find a method to update the already existing po(t) file adding new string, removing no more used ones, but keeping the existing ones.

In large application it's a pain to "merge" translations by hand.

Is there an option to use with the `extract` command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such command, no, the i18n shell is purely for extracting messages into translation template files, no merging/updating.

Merging/updating has to be done using external tools, like for example **[Poedit](https://poedit.net)**, which provides a GUI for the **[gettext tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext)**. Use such a tool to create `.po` (and `.mo`) files from your `.pot` template files, and then after making changes in your app code, re-extract the `.pot` template files via the i18n shell, and use the external tool's [**merging/updating functionality**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgmerge-Invocation.html#msgmerge-Invocation) to update your existing `.po` files from the new `.pot` template files.

gettext's merging functionality will give you pretty good results, look out for [**fuzzy**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Fuzzy-Entries.html#Fuzzy-Entries) and [**obsolete**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Obsolete-Entries.html#Obsolete-Entries) entries after merging, they can require some additional manual work, but mostly things usually work out fine automatically.